# ProtoRPC App Engine Hello World test app not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protorpc

I have been trying to get the rather simple Hello World ProtoRPC App Engine example to work, but to no avail. The code from the website just doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I have looked at a number of possible solutions, but couldn't find a complete working set. Any help would be much appreciated! You can see the error (or lack thereof) below:

**app.yaml**

```
application: proto-test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /hello.*
  script: hello.py
```

**hello.py**

```
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote
from protorpc.wsgi import service

package = 'hello'

# Create the request string containing the user's name
class HelloRequest(messages.Message):
    my_name = messages.StringField(1, required=True)

# Create the response string
class HelloResponse(messages.Message):
    hello = messages.StringField(1, required=True)

# Create the RPC service to exchange messages
class HelloService(remote.Service):

    @remote.method(HelloRequest, HelloResponse)
    def hello(self, request):
        return HelloResponse(hello='Hello there, %s!' % request.my_name)

# Map the RPC service and path (/hello)
app = service.service_mappings([('/hello', HelloService)])
```

**curl command**

```
curl -H 'content-type:application/json' -d '{"my_name":"test1"}' http://proto-test.appspot.com/hello.hello
```

When I run the above command in the command line, it just returns the prompt without an error. My logs suggest that the curl command sort of worked, but it just didn't provide a response. This is what appears in the logs:

```
2013-05-08 22:27:07.409 /hello.hello 200 522ms 0kb curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
2620:0:10c8:1007:a800:1ff:fe00:33af - - [08/May/2013:14:27:07 -0700] "POST /hello.hello HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - "curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3" "proto-test.appspot.com" ms=523 cpu_ms=133 loading_request=1 app_engine_release=1.8.0 instance=00c61b117c66197ad84ad9bc61485b292e5129

I 2013-05-08 22:27:07.409
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

An Ajax call through the Chrome JS Console returned the following: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**:

```
$.ajax({url: ‘/hello.hello’, type: 'POST', contentType: 'application/json', data: ‘{ "my_name": "Bob" }’,dataType: 'json',success: function(response){alert(response.hello);}});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java script you posted seems to have syntax errors.  Mainly, it looks like you are using the ` character in places instead of the ' character.

The reason why your request is not working is because of how you wrote the app.yaml file.  You are using the old Python 2.5 way of calling applications by referring to a script rather than a WSGI application.  You can correct it by changing the url handler in app.yaml to:

handlers:
- url: /hello.*
  script: hello.app